# Determine Touch Input Consumer

Tags: android, event-handling, touch

I have a view roughly defined as

```java
class MyView1 extends LinearLayout {
        // for debugging, not actually needed
        @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "");
        }

        // also for debugging, not actually needed
        @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
            boolean handle = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "handle?=" + handle);
            return handle;
        }
    }
}
```

and a TouchListener / Behavior as

```java
class TouchBehavior implements View.OnTouchListener {
    View myView; // assigned in ctor
    public void attach() { myView.setOnTouchListener( this ); }
    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "log just for detection");
        // actual logic...
    }
```

which attaches to `MyView1` (verified with logging).  This logic works well on another view `MyView2` (which also extends `LinearLayout`) but not for `MyView1` for reasons I've yet to determine.  In `MyView1` touch-events (tapping anywhere within the layout) are detected in `onInterceptTouchEvent` but not in `onTouchEvent`.  `TouchBehavior.onTouchEvent()` is never invoked when `TouchBehavior` is attached to `MyView1` regardless of whether either or both of `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` are defined on `MyView1`.

From Android docs' [Managing Touch Events in a ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) it is my understanding that `onInterceptTouchEvent()` is called when a touch event is detected in a `ViewGroup` and it can return `true` to indicate that it will intercept/consume the event and not propagate to its children.  In my example, `MyView1.onInterceptTouchEvent` is returning false using its super-class logic which means it is available for consumption by itself or children.  However, since `MyView1.onTouchEvent` is not invoked I think the event is consumed by a child sub-view.

Having said all of that, maybe the problem is obvious to someone else but it leads me to think that the event is consumed by a child sub-view or one of its listeners and so have searched for a way to determine the final consumer of that `MotionEvent`.  `MyView1` and `MyView2` each have 8-10 subviews (layout/widget/etc) and are very different structurally.

So how can I determine which `View` has consumed some input event (`MotionEvent`)?

Comment: Your thoughts are right, but I cannot remind any nice way for detecting which view has eventually consumed the touch event. The only way I can think of is to create custom views instead of original views and debug their `onTouch()`callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follow. Set a breaking point at `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent` method. If you are using SDK 25 then you can use line 2266. The `child` `View` there is the one who consume the touch event.

You can also configure the break point there so that the IDE will log to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Myview extends LinearLayout {
    public Myview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Myview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public Myview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onTouchEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onInterceptTouchEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean handle = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        return handle;
    }


}
```

In above TouchBehavior class `OnTouch` method you should return false.
If you return true only `onInterceptTouchEvent` method will fire. If you return false both `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` will fire